# Mapping de-multiplexers on FPGAs

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i have seen some ways of efficient mapping of multiplexers on fpga, but what happens for demultiplexers? are there any specific quidelines? does pipelining make sense? is it meaningful to brake the demuxes to minimize number of outputs just like the number of inputs in a multiplexer?

Comment: What do you mean with de-multiplexer? Sending one source of data to multiple outputs, or input-enable for a specific signal. I don't see a use-case for such a component.

Comment: Normally, you  should avoid demultiplexer structures entirely in any digital circuit for all data paths. demultiplexers should only be used for control signals. This design rule can save you dozens to thousands of logic gates -- and at the end LUTs.

Comment: i have to optimise a code that has several 'case-when' statements where the input is the same but based on a control signal it is assigned to a different output, kind of the opposite of a typical multiplexer...

Comment: @JHBonarius: the 74138 is the canonical decoder/demultiplexer. Hold the enables active, and you get a decoder, or use an interesting signal as an enable, and you get a demultiplexer. It's difficult to envisage building any useful circuit without a 138 or equivalent.

Comment: @user2609910: look up an implementation, such as the logic diagram at http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls138.pdf. A 4-in LUT can generate a single output bit of a structure like this (with one enable, ie signal to route to the output). Once you get to a 6-to-64, you have too many bits for a 6-in LUT, so you have to start chaining, which is the only complication.

Comment: @EML yes, by holding the input/D at '1', you get a binary to one-hot decoder. But I don't think that is the use-case here, look at his comment/answer below. Using select logic would make more sense. Another use-case for a demultiplexer would be a deserializer. But that requires a different (high-speed design) approach.

Comment: @user2609910 Before trying to implement a *demultiplexer* you should probably answer the following questions: 1) what value do you want to send to the non-selected outputs? 2) If the answer to question 1) is *I don't care*, why not sending the same value to **all** outputs and replace this *demultiplexer* by simple wires?